# How to count a specific value of selected option in a table in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have select tags in my table. I need to count if any of the selected option in those select tags have **optional** as its value. If any of the select tag has **optional** value selected then i will show a text field under it. But I could not do it properly. Here is my code.

```
<html>
     <table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="subject_tb">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="30%">Subject Name</th>
                    <th width="20%" class="text-center"><span style="margin-left:-64px">Choice</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="subject_table">

                <tr>
                    <td>Bangla</td>
                    <td class="td-actions text-right">
                        <select name="select_mandatory"
                                class="selectpicker select_mandatory"
                                data-style="btn-default btn-block btn-outline"
                                data-menu-style="dropdown-blue" required>
                            <option value="0" class="mandatory">Mandatory
                            </option>
                            <option value="1" class="optional">Optional
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>English</td>
         <td class="td-actions text-right">
         <select name="select_mandatory"class="selectpicker select_mandatory" 
              data-style="btn-default btn-block btn-outline" data-menu 
              style="dropdown-blue" required>
         <option value="0" class="mandatory">Mandatory</option>
         <option value="1" class="optional">Optional
         </option>
         </select>
         </td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
        <div class="row" id="optional_subject_number">
                        <label class="col-sm-8 col-form-label">Total 
        Optional Subject Per Students
                </label>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">
               <input class="form-control" type="number" 
          name="optional_subject" value="" number="true"
                                       id="optional_subject" style="margin-left: -100% !important;"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</html>
         <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0
        $("#subject_tb tbody tr td").each(function(){
            console.log($(this))
            var value = $(this).find('select').val();
            if(value === '1')
                {
                    count++;
                }
             console.log(count)

            if(count >= 0){
                $('#optional_subject_number').show();
            }
            else{
                $('#optional_subject_number').hide();
            }
            });
    });
</script>
```

If you could help me with the code then it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no element having id="optional_subject_number
" in the html you have provided here. Please edit the html so that we can understand the problem in more details.

Comment: I have updated the code. You may check. @SantuRoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add on "change" event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //hide by default
  $(this).find('#optional_subject_number').hide();

  $( "select" ).change(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $("#subject_tb tbody tr").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).find('select').val();
        count = count + parseInt(value);
    });
    if(count>0){
        $('#optional_subject_number').show();
    }else{
        $('#optional_subject_number').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrestnyL/11/

Comment: It's working in fiddle. but in my project its not working.

Comment: Hmm.. if you copy paste this code, the only difference is that it does not incude jQuery explicitly (jsfiddle includes it in background) - include <script src="path/to/your/jquery.js"></script>. I've tried that on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: jQuery is added. That's not the problem i guess. Its working in static data but when table value is coming from the server dynamically its creating a problem I guess.

Comment: Ahaaa, then that may be an issue. Can you provide a more concrete example? My guess would be that events you are listening are not correct.

Comment: Just give me some time. It's a part of some other code. I will update you shortly.

Comment: Sorry for delay. The problem was I have append data to the table, so any event was not working in the dropdown, so had to modify the event a little bit, by adding the class after the change event, then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing but you need reset count each loop.

```
$("#subject_tb tbody tr td").each(function(){
  count = 0; //Reset count
  ...
})
```

Comment: I have to show the input div after the table if any of the select option has 'optional' as its value. That's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to count the option if the selected value is *1 (Optional)*, you have to do the count on the `change` event of the *select*.

Also I believe, you want to show the element when `if(count > 0){` not when `if(count >= 0){`.

You can try the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var el = $('#optional_subject_number');
  var count = 0;
  $('.selectpicker').change(function(){
    $(this).val() == '1'? count++ : count--;
    if(count > 0){ 
      $(el).text('Total Optional Subject Per Students ' + count);
      $(el).show();
    }
    else{
      $(el).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="subject_tb">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th width="30%">Subject Name</th>
          <th width="20%" class="text-center"><span style="margin-left:-64px">Choice</span>
          </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="subject_table">
    <tr>
      <td>Bangla</td>
      <td class="td-actions text-right">
        <select name="select_mandatory"
                class="selectpicker select_mandatory"
                data-style="btn-default btn-block btn-outline"
                data-menu-style="dropdown-blue" required>
            <option value="0" class="mandatory">Mandatory
            </option>
            <option value="1" class="optional">Optional
            </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>English</td>
      <td class="td-actions text-right">
        <select name="select_mandatory"class="selectpicker select_mandatory" 
        data-style="btn-default btn-block btn-outline" data-menu 
        style="dropdown-blue" required>
        <option value="0" class="mandatory">Mandatory</option>
        <option value="1" class="optional">Optional
        </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="row" id="optional_subject_number">
    <label class="col-sm-8 col-form-label">
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="number" 
  name="optional_subject" value="" number="true"
                   id="optional_subject" style="margin-left: -100% !important;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a script for select value change event. Here is what you can do and if you need any more clarification, let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subject_tb tbody tr td select").change();
  });

  $(document).on("change", "#subject_tb tbody tr td select", function(){
      var count = 0;
      $("#subject_tb tbody tr td select").each(function(){

          var value = $(this).val();
          if(value === '1')
          {
              count++;
          }

          if(count >= 1)
          {
            $('#optional_subject_number').show();
          }
          else
          {
            $('#optional_subject_number').hide();
          }


      });

  });
```